# Xorg says “couldn't open module intel" but intel_drv.so exists

Tags: xorg, drivers

In my `Xorg.0.log` there are these lines:

```
[ 36753.331] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[ 36753.331] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module intel
```

and

```
[ 36753.331] (II) LoadModule: "radeon"
[ 36753.331] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.so
```

The issue is that both `intel_drv.so` and `radeon_drv.so` are present, while only one of them is successfully loaded:

```
[c4thewin@LenovoG500-C4tW ~]$ ls /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers
ati_drv.so  fbdev_drv.so  intel_drv.so  modesetting_drv.so  radeon_drv.so  vesa_drv.so
```

I also read that `modprobe` needs `.ko` libraries as argument, so...

Is it not `modprobe` that's run behind the scenes?
Why is it that `intel_drv.so` can't be loaded even though it exists?

edit:

```
[c4thewin@LenovoG500-C4tW ~]$ lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [8086:0154] (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port [8086:0151] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1e10] (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1e12] (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e59] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 4-port SATA Controller [IDE mode] [8086:1e01] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
00:1f.5 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 2-port SATA Controller [IDE mode] [8086:1e09] (rev 04)
01:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun PRO [Radeon HD 8570A/8570M] [1002:6663]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet [1969:10a0] (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
[c4thewin@LenovoG500-C4tW ~]$ cat /sys/class/graphics/fb*/name
inteldrmfb
[c4thewin@LenovoG500-C4tW ~]$ cd /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers
[c4thewin@LenovoG500-C4tW drivers]$ ls -l .
total 2316
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   10440 Mar 16 22:38 ati_drv.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   23624 Nov 22  2016 fbdev_drv.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1719632 Apr 20 17:30 intel_drv.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   86272 Apr  7 20:46 modesetting_drv.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  493896 Mar 16 22:38 radeon_drv.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   27696 Nov 21  2016 vesa_drv.so
[c4thewin@LenovoG500-C4tW drivers]$ ldd intel_drv.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffb1d5d000)
    libpciaccess.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpciaccess.so.0 (0x00007fb37a835000)
    libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007fb37a58d000)
    libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb37a27b000)
    libudev.so.1 => /usr/lib/libudev.so.1 (0x00007fb37a25a000)
    libdrm_intel.so.1 => /usr/lib/libdrm_intel.so.1 (0x00007fb37a036000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007fb379e25000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb379c05000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb379860000)
    /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000056245148b000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /usr/lib/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fb37964a000)
    libcap.so.2 => /usr/lib/libcap.so.2 (0x00007fb379446000)
    librt.so.1 => /usr/lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007fb37923e000)
[c4thewin@LenovoG500-C4tW drivers]$ ldd radeon_drv.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc65de5000)
    libdrm_radeon.so.1 => /usr/lib/libdrm_radeon.so.1 (0x00007f9e642d8000)
    libudev.so.1 => /usr/lib/libudev.so.1 (0x00007f9e642b7000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9e63f12000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f9e63d01000)
    libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9e639ef000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /usr/lib/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f9e637d9000)
    libcap.so.2 => /usr/lib/libcap.so.2 (0x00007f9e635d3000)
    librt.so.1 => /usr/lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007f9e633cb000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f9e631ad000)
    /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055d9f46ff000)
```

Comment: The X drivers and kernel drivers have no connection, so no, X doesn't run `modprobe`. One possible reason X cannot open modules is version/library mismatch. Do an `ldd` on `intel_drv.so` and `radeon_drv.so`, and compare. Also check the versions in your package manager.

Comment: @dirkt Sorry for being nooby but all I found "suspicious" is that `intel_drv.so` needs `libm.so.6`, `libc.so.6`, `libpthread.so.0` and `librt.so.1` all of which are sym-links (that came with the `glibc` package) to `lib<something>-2.25.so` and which are up-to-date. Every other dependency is a sym-link to libraries of the same version. Is this what you suggested checking?

Comment: I realize that the question might be a bit too broad. I'll try editing it a bit soon.

Comment: Please edit question with full output of `ldd intel_drv.so` and `ldd radeon_drv.so` just in case it's really fishy (but if no library links are broken, it should be fine). While we are at it, include output of `ls -l /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers` in case permissions are screwed up. Do you actually have an Intel graphics card? Include output of `lspci -nn` and `cat /sys/class/graphics/fb*/name`, just in case.

Comment: @dirkt Done (not sure if SE automatically notifies on edit).

Comment: All looks in order as far as I can tell. I noticed `intel_drv` is the newest driver. Is the X server itself also the latest version? If not, try to upgrade is.

Comment: @dirkt Yep, `1.19.3-2` at the moment.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Last resort would be to get a build of the X server with debugging symbols and set breakpoints in [loadmod.c](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/tree/hw/xfree86/loader/loadmod.c) to see why it fails. According to the code, it just searches for the presence of `intel_drv.so`, so it *should* succeed...

Comment: @dirkt That actually sounds pretty interesting. I might just try that sometimes soon. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm running into this same exact issue. Any new information?

Comment: Just for the record. I am facing the same problem.